# Why button moves down although it is specified as inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap and css. I researched but could not find an answer for this or a similar case.
I put a `<div class="col-md-6">` inside which I add two divs one of which class is "col-md-4" and the other one is "col-md-2". So in this case, the child divs should fit in the parent div and be in the same line, but somehow the second child div moves down. I used style="display:inline" in the second child div but it didn't really work. When I remove the parent div of which class is "col-md-6", it works as I want but I don't understand why they don't fit in the parent div although its size is big enough to contain both child divs in the same line.

This doesn't work the way I want;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="addItem" style="display: inline;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline;">submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

This one does;

```
  <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="addItem" style="display: inline;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline;">submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Did you intend to nest columns like that in your first snippet? That's non-standard. A column should have a row between it and outer columns or containers.

Comment: This is because `col-*` elements are designed to be flex children. The reason the bottom one works is because `row` is a flex parent. The one that doesn't work is because `col-*` are not flex parents, so `col-*` will be a block element with `100%` width.

Comment: Great Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time that you want to make a col, it must be inside a new row. This is because row splits in 12 columns the grid. If you put a col inside a col, the grid doesn't exist and this is why your code fail.

Here you have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" id="addItem" style="display: inline;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline;">submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer came while I was writing. We are talking about the same things. +1